# changing colorbar sensitivity

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I re edited the question in order to make it more clear with what I need help. So I have the following code so far

```
#import the libraries
import netCDF4 as nc
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#check what variables are included
# in our case : dict_keys(['time', 'time_bnds', 'lat', 'lat_bnds', 'lon', 'lon_bnds', 'height', 'tas'])
print(data.variables.keys())



#extract the data
lats = data.variables['lat'][:]
lons = data.variables['lon'][:]
time = data.variables['time'][:]
te = data.variables['tas'][:]-273.5

#extract the coordinates we want to plot (Italy)by inputting lower #left and top right coordinates

italy = Basemap(projection='merc',
       #ITALY
       llcrnrlon=  6.63,
       llcrnrlat=   35.29,
       urcrnrlon=   18.78, 
       urcrnrlat=   47.09,
       resolution= 'f')


#create the plot
lon,lat =np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
x,y=italy(lon,lat)

c_scheme = italy.pcolor(x,y,np.squeeze(te[0,:,:]), cmap ='jet')
italy.drawcoastlines()
italy.drawstates()
italy.drawcounties()
cbar = italy.colorbar(c_scheme, location='right',pad='10%')

plt.title('KIOST-ESM')
plt.show()
```

which creates the following heat map
[image]

Now what I want is to make the plot identify(colour) smaller differences between the temperatures. However I do not know exactly how to find the min and max value of my area that I am investigating (this time it is Italy). My variable te that has the temperatures is of the type : numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray with shape (9125, 160, 320) [time,lon,lat]

Comment: [Provide vmin and vmax](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html)?

Comment: Hey @Mr.T thank you for the reply. My problem is that I do not know how to find the min and max value because my the variable is [time,lon,lat] and I do not know how to make it find the min values in the area that I am looking for. I will edit my question to add the part how I take the area I want to investigate

Comment: Hey @Mr.T I updated the whole question and put my code as well. Hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Setting `vmin` and `vmax` values should solve this. please try

```
min_height = int(np.min(np.squeeze(te[0,:,:])))
max_height = int(np.max(np.squeeze(te[0,:,:])))
c_scheme = italy.pcolor(x,y,np.squeeze(te[0,:,:]), cmap ='jet', vmin=min_height, vmax=max_height)
```

In the case that the `te` array holds is bigger than the mesh in `x` and `y`, I would try doing the following:

```
min_height = int(np.min(np.squeeze(te[0,x,y])))
max_height = int(np.max(np.squeeze(te[0,x,y])))
```

Comment: Hey Tomer, thank you for your input. However, won t np.min(np.squeeze(te[0,:,:])) find the min value of my te variable? The problem is I do not want to find the min value of the temperature in the whole te, but between the coordinates where Italy is (the box that is created inside the Basemap function basically)

Comment: It looks like you are creating a mesh of `x` and `y` and then using `np.squeeze(te[0,:,:])`  for the color. This means that the size of `np.squeeze(te[0,:,:])` needs to be the same size of the mesh. I think this is not all the `te` values, as in the 1st dimension you only take index '0' and squeeze it. Is doing this changes anything? @Alex

Comment: Hey Tomer. te[0,:,:] takes the 1st day of the netcdf file and all the temperatures for all longitude and latitude . I believe basemap basically just plots the values within the box that I want. Because inside the Basemap I define the desired box that I want to be plotted. I will try what you say once I am home and I ll get back with you

Comment: In that case I would perhaps try `min_height = np.min(np.squeeze(te[0,x,y]))` and the same with the max, I updated the answer for that as well @Alex

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. I get the following error arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Comment: @Alex, Change to `min_height = int(np.min(np.squeeze(te[0,x,y])))` and the same for max, and please try again

Comment: unfortunately i get the same error